# Align & Indent Array Elements - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'd like to align `double` array elements to the right side of the relevant String array element.

*Example Output:*

```
TITLE         TICKET TYPE        COST
-------------------------------------
Tulip Garden  Entry             $10.0
              Tour + Ride       $20.0
-------------------------------------
Museum        Entry              $0.0
              Guided Tour        $5.0
-------------------------------------
...
```

Below is what I've done so far.

*EventData.java*

```
private String[] ticketTypeTitle;
private double[] ticketTypeCost;

...

public String[] getTicketTitles() { return this.ticketTypeTitle; }
public double[] getTicketCosts() { return this.ticketTypeCost; }
```

*Main.java*

```
String pattern = "%-28s %-28s %-1s";

System.out.printf(pattern, "TITLE", "TICKET TYPE", "COST");
System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------);

for (int i = 0; i < eventCount; i++ {
    System.out.format(pattern, eventData[i].getTitle(), String.join("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t", eventData[i].getTicketTitles(), "$" + String.join("\n\t\t\t\t\t\t", Arrays.toString(eventData[i].getTicketCosts().replaceAll("\\[|\\]|\\,", "")));
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
}
```

**Problem #1:** At the first line in the `for` loop, I'm not able to get the dollar symbol to display before every array element (for the ticket costs only).

**Problem #2:** I want the cost values to line up with the ticket type as well, similar to my output example above, however I haven't figured out how to do that.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use `printf()` to also print the lines of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a separate formatter for the numbers to ensure they're formatted to the right. I've also added the $ sign straight into the formatter pattern. See below.

Here's a sample code of what could work for you:

```
String[] titleArray = {"title1", "title2", "title3", "title4", "title5"};
String[] typeArray = {"type1", "type2", "type3", "type4", "type5"};
double[] costArray = { 10.0, 20.0, 0.0, 5.0, 3.33 };

String pattern = "%-28s %-28s $%5.2f";
String patternHeader = "%-28s %-28s %-1s";

System.out.printf(patternHeader, "TITLE", "TICKET TYPE", "COST");
System.out.println();
System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    System.out.format(pattern, titleArray[i], typeArray[i], costArray[i]);
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
```